# Insert hashtags in python string

Tags: python, regex

I try to insert '#' in front of specific words in a sentence with an elegant solution (not a big function with many 'if').

```
hashwords = ['Google','Apple','Titan','Facebook']

input = 'Google,Apple, Titan and Facebook. Not Facebook@Work OpenTitan or apple.'

output = '#Google,#Apple, #Titan and #Facebook. Not Facebook@Work, OpenTitan or apple.'
```

I tried things like that, but I would like to take into account the punctuation or words that can be part of bigger words :

```
    for elem in hashwords :
        if elem in input:
            input = input.replace(elem, '#'+elem)
```

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: `re.sub(rf'\b(?:{"|".join(hashwords)})\b', r'#\g<0>', text)`?

Comment: `Facebook@work` gets still hashtagged

Comment: `re.sub(rf'\b(?<!@)(?:{"|".join(hashwords)})\b(?!@)', r'#\g<0>', text)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import re

hashwords = ['Google','Apple','Titan','Facebook']
input = 'Google,Apple, Titan and Facebook. Not Facebook@Work OpenTitan or apple.'

for elem in hashwords :
    input = re.sub(r'\b'+elem+r'\b(?!@)', '#'+elem, input)
print(input)
```

**Output:**

```
#Google,#Apple, #Titan and #Facebook. Not Facebook@Work OpenTitan or apple.
```

You can use `r'(?<!@)\b'+elem+r'\b(?!@)'` if you don't want `Apple@Titan` to be matched.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Toto!

Comment: Note that the performance will drop a lot once there are thousands of search terms. Also, if search words contain whitespaces, the solution will be different.